# Panda group dataframe based on datetime type into different period ignoring date part

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to group the rows into groups, based on variable time interval.
However, when doing grouping, I want to ignore the date part, only group based on the time date.

Say I want to group every 5 minutes.

```
       timestampe            val
0  2016-08-11 11:03:00        0.1
1  2016-08-13 11:06:00        0.3
2  2016-08-09 11:04:00        0.5
3  2016-08-05 11:35:00        0.7
4  2016-08-19 11:09:00        0.8
5  2016-08-21 12:37:00        0.9

        into 

       timestampe             val
0  2016-08-11 11:03:00        0.1
2  2016-08-09 11:04:00        0.5

       timestampe             val
1  2016-08-13 11:06:00        0.3
4  2016-08-19 11:09:00        0.8

       timestampe             val
3  2016-08-05 11:35:00        0.7
       timestampe             val
5  2016-08-21 12:37:00        0.9
```

Notice as long as the time is within the same 5 minutes interval, the rows are grouped, regardless of the date.

Comment: I tried TimeGrouper, which takes date into consideration. Also tried to create an additional column with only time partition, but it somehow does not allow me to use TimeGrouper anymore.

Comment: There are unanswered questions.  Do you want the 5 minute interval to begin with the first observation?  Meaning, first observation is 11:03, get all rows up to a time of 11:08.  If so, imagine you take the 11:03 and that's followed by an 11:45, followed by 11:07.  Do you want to group the 11:03 and 11:07 then the next group starts with 11:45?  Or, do you want to sort by time first?  If that is true, then the time of the first row is arbitrary.  Or, are you content with splitting the day into 5 minute windows?

Comment: @piRSquared Splitting the day into 5-minute windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming you split the day up into 5 minute windows

```
df.groupby(df.timestampe.dt.hour.mul(60) \
             .add(df.timestampe.dt.minute) // 5) \
  .apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index)
```

[image]

---

```
for name, group in df.groupby(df.timestampe.dt.hour.mul(60).add(df.timestampe.dt.minute) // 5):
    print name
    print group
    print

132
           timestampe  val
0 2016-08-11 11:03:00  0.1
2 2016-08-09 11:04:00  0.5

133
           timestampe  val
1 2016-08-13 11:06:00  0.3
4 2016-08-19 11:09:00  0.8

139
           timestampe  val
3 2016-08-05 11:35:00  0.7

151
           timestampe  val
5 2016-08-21 12:37:00  0.9
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself clear. so the 5-minute windows should not only apply to 1-hour range. 11:35 but 12:37 should be in different windows.
Your solution only takes on minute portion.

Comment: @9blue Fixed post.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not care about the `date` part of your `datetime` object, I think that make all `date` equal is a good trick.

```
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=2000, month=1, day=1))
```

You get:

```
            timestamp  val                time
0 2016-08-11 11:03:00  0.1 2000-01-01 11:03:00
1 2016-08-13 11:06:00  0.3 2000-01-01 11:06:00
2 2016-08-09 11:04:00  0.5 2000-01-01 11:04:00
3 2016-08-05 11:35:00  0.7 2000-01-01 11:35:00
4 2016-08-19 11:09:00  0.8 2000-01-01 11:09:00
5 2016-08-21 11:37:00  0.9 2000-01-01 11:37:00
```

Now you can do what you what on `time` column. For example, groups on every 5 mins:

```
grouped = df.groupby(Grouper(key='time', freq='5min'))

grouped.count()

                     timestamp  val
time                               
2000-01-01 11:00:00          2    2
2000-01-01 11:05:00          2    2
2000-01-01 11:10:00          0    0
2000-01-01 11:15:00          0    0
2000-01-01 11:20:00          0    0
2000-01-01 11:25:00          0    0
2000-01-01 11:30:00          0    0
2000-01-01 11:35:00          2    2
```

Hope this trick may be suitable for your need. Thanks!